# Python: How to convert a long number to ascii?

Tags: python-2.7

There is a error:"OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long", When I try to convert a very long number(like 1000000000000000000) to ascii, How could I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site. Your question is unclear. I can see the error but at least you should show us the basic part of your code. So we can fix it or give you some advice.

Comment: How are you trying to do the conversion? `str(1000000000000000000)` works.